# Texture coordinates on different size of rectangles

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I mapped texture coordinates like:

```
static float texCoord[] = {
0, 1,
1, 1,
1, 0,
0, 0
};
```

And by drawing it:

```
void Rectangle::Draw()
{
const float vertices[] = {
    x, y,
    x + width, y,
    x, y - height,
    x + width, y - height
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glColor3ub(255, 255, 255);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2, texCoord);

if      (IsTypeHorizontal()) glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_H);
else /* (IsTypeVertical())*/ glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_V);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

}
```

Texture drawn in vertical (height > width) is good but in horizontal (height < width), texture appears to be inverted. Even if I separate the texture coordinates by `texCoord_H` and `texCoord_V`, image drawn is still inverted?

What do I still need to know ? What is the problem here in my code?

PS. I upload texture in OpenGL using SOIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many times of changing and swapping texture coordinates, I realize that I've wasted my time. The real problem is here

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2, texCoord);
```

3rd parameter (w/c is the `stride`) 'causes the bug, it should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
static float texCoord[] = {
0, 1,
1, 1,
0, 0,
1, 0
};
```

Comment: I draw a quad using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` not `GL_QUADS`

Comment: Ok, I only noticed that the texcoords and positions didn't match up, in that case swap the two last s coords.

Comment: What `s coords`? I think that is not the problem there. `texcoords` and `vertices` are using same plotting of vertex(i.e like 'Z')

Comment: No they're not, the positions are a 'Z', the texcoords are not.

Comment: Uhm yeah. I got the wrong one. But still no luck even I swap the last two or even make a new mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Most OpenGL newbies get confused by the fact, that with the usual set of projection, transforms and viewport mapping parameters OpenGL considers image origin to be in the lower left and coordinates increating toward the right and up. This is in contrast to most computer graphics systems that assume the origin to be in the upper left and vertical dimension increasing downwards.

Probably that is your issue.